# JCombobox using hasmap/ no point model

Tags: java, jcombobox

Hey i am looking for solving a problem i need to make a model for jcombobox.
I have a :

```
 Map<Integer, Pathes_format> profiles =new HashMap<Integer, Pathes_format>();
```

I wana to show on jcombobox pathes_format.getname will be displayed at index pathes_format.GetiD  i never wrote or touch a abstract class or models.

Here what i made

```
package subDialogs;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

import json.Pathes_format;

public class PatheseModel implements ComboBoxModel {

Map<Integer, Pathes_format> profiles =new HashMap<Integer, Pathes_format>();
int index=-1;
@Override
public int getSize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return profiles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return profiles.get(index);
}

@Override
public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Object getSelectedItem() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
//void addElement(Object obj){
//  
//}
void insertElementAt(Object obj, int index) {
    profiles.put(index, (Pathes_format) obj);

}
void removeElement(Object obj) {
    Pathes_format tmp = profiles.get(obj);
    tmp=null;

}
void removeElementAt(int index){
    profiles.remove(index);

}

}
```

I don't know is this correct :/. Mby i should make for a format patches single not for map; and add ability to add map??

Comment: `enum`s are not meant to work like signals or semaphores. Probably you want an `int[]` that is filled by 0s and a single 1.

Comment: Yaaa good idea but still i wana know how it would look settings enums and allowing one to be true in constructor or what ever- because i wanna know just...

Comment: Well, you can create a method in the enum that will update `tryb` to false for all elements and then update `tryb` to `true` to the current enum and use this method instead of doing this manually.

Comment: And what parametr should it take, what type.. that what is my point
public void negogitate(what here)

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't need a parameter at all.

Comment: Mby this??
    public void negotitate(RunType a){
         normal.set(false);
         localfile.set(false);
         override_infofile.set(false);
         urldownload.set(false);
         or_info_url.set(false);
         a.set(true);
        }